# Is there a DDD (Data Display Debugger) plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, debugging

Can I use DDD (Data Display Debugger) in Eclipse, either by configuring Eclipse or by using a plugin?

If you want to know why, look at this :

[image]

that's the contents of an array.

Or, even better, IMO, this:

[image]

see that top pane? A lifesaver for debugging lists or structures with many pointers!

But I just can't figure out how to incorporate it into Eclipse. Can it be done? (or, is there a windows port of DDD?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No answers, so it looks like there isn't one.

I would have deleted this question, but will leave it here in case anyone searches for the same thing in future.